# NameError: undefined local variable or method `broadcast_messages' for #<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x007f4d099fb6b0>

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Title error when accessing ActiveRecord model only on heroku with rails 5.0.0-beta1.  Works on production env heroku.  Problem persists anytime Rails.logger is set to STDOUT wether between gem 'rails_stdout_logging' or in config/environment/production.rb

I've reviewed implementation and see broadcast_messages as a method created by the accessor macro.  I'm at a loss and am looking for suggestions to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out heroku's rails_stdout_logging gem which is included as part of heroku's rails_12factor gem has a bug with rails 5.0.0-beta1.

StdoutLogger inherits from stdlib's Logger rather than ActiveSupport's Logger via < ::Logger.  I've got a workaround on my fork but it injects an ActiveSupport dependency when not using rails.  I'm new to ruby so I don't know best practice to make a more eloquent fix.

See https://github.com/MattWalston/rails_stdout_logging.

Comment: It was fixed on master https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22933 it should be in Rails Beta 2, otherwise you can point your `rails` copy in the Gemfile to the master branch in github.